# getting filename of created file each time

Tags: python

my code is doing mostly a generation of xml based on a template , but I want to print every new filename after `generate` is executed , but I think I code it in the wrong way. how can I make work to print every filename after generation?

```
def ReturnSuccess(string):
    print(GREEN + BOLD + '[+] ' + END + string)
```

```
def generate(self):
        import os
        try:
            filepath = "./common"
            with open (os.path.join(filepath, randomString(8)+".xml"), "w") as a:
                for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
                    for filename in files:
                        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
                        template = open('./templates/build.xml','r')
                        template = template.read()
                        template = template.replace("STRING",randomString(8))
                    a.write(template)
                    ReturnSuccess("Generated stager successfully")
                    ReturnInfo("Launch with {filename}")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not generate directory listing file.")
```

output

```
[+] Generated  successfully
[*] Launch with 'data.exe HnqBbDbr.xml'
[+] Generated stager successfully
[*] Launch with 'data.exe data.py'
```

desired

```
[+] Generated stager successfully
[*] Launch with 'data.exe HnqBbDbr.xml'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 3 lines beginning with `a.write(template)` be inside the `for filename in files:` loop?

Comment: Where is `Generated  successfully` coming from? The `Generated` line doesn't have a variable for `stager`.

Comment: if I add `a.write(template)` inside the loop , the xml it will be incrase the times I generate the content similar to `n+1`

Comment: Each time through the loop you're replacing `template` and `filename`. If you do it after the loop, you only get the last filename and template.

Comment: `Generated successfully` is a pre-made function which display the text with color

Comment: how can I do it in a code level?

Comment: Do you mean that's what `ReturnSuccess()` does?

Comment: How does `ReturnSuccess("Generated stager successfully")` print `[+] Generated successfully` without saying `stager` in the middle?

Comment: yeah . it is a pre-made function

Comment: I still don't understand how the word `stager` is disappearing from the output.

Comment: I also don't see how `ReturnInfo("Launch with {filename}")` is putting two filenames into the message. That can't be the output from this script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198960/discussion-between-barmar-and-alfredo-rivas).

Comment: I update the code why its happening

Comment: Please come to chat

Comment: I'm leaving in 1 minute if you don't join the chat.